# C# WPF проверка CheckBox по нумерации

Tags: c#, checkbox

Доброе время суток!
Хочу создать окно авторизации, при условии что CheckBox должны быть выделены по очередности... 
Если чек боксы выделяются так 1,2,3,4 то авторизация пройдена, в противном случае Ошибка! Например если пользователь будет выделять CheckBox, не по нумерации а 2,3,1,4. в таком порядке, то .[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подпишите все чекбоксы на 1 событие. Далее берите в этом событие имя элементов и записывайте в любую переменную (можно даже в стринг). Ну и проверяйте ее на соответсвие.

Comment: Заведите переменную `шаг`, в начале она равна 0, потом проверяете, если выделен первый чекбокс и шаг=0, то шаг=1, иначе шаг=0. Если выделен второй чекбокс и шаг=1, то шаг=2, иначе шаг=0 и т.д., остается только при ситуации шаг=4 давать админские права.